# How can i loop the response of my JSON Object?

Tags: java, android

I am having an error of `data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Here is the look of my response

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "data": {
        "email": "sample@gmail.com",
        "session_code": "samplesession"
    }
}
```

here is my code

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Config.login, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

            JSONArray details = obj.getJSONArray("data");


            if (status_code == 200) {
                Log.d("success_to",response);


                for (int i=0; i<details.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = details.getJSONObject(i);

                    String email = object.getString("email");

                    Log.d("sample_email", email);

                }

                finish();

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class));

            }else{

                Log.d("error_to","error 404 na");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i am still new in android and i am still learning the process, can somebody help me with my problem, this really is killing my time in fixing this error.

Comment: you are tried to convert jsonobject to array. there is no array in your rsponse

Comment: how can i loop through it? i am trying to get the email of it. sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: Use `JSONObject details = obj.getJSONObject("data");`

Comment: @JanessaBautista check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no array in your json so try like below

```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
   JSONObject data=obj.optJSONObject("data");
   String email = data.getString("email");
```

Remove below line from your code

```
JSONArray details = obj.getJSONArray("data");
 for (int i=0; i<details.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = details.getJSONObject(i);
      String email = object.getString("email");
      Log.d("sample_email", email);
     }
```